# The property or field 'Id' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed

Tags: development, csom

I have this CSOM code:-

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group group = context.Site.RootWeb.SiteGroups.GetByName(webname);                 
context.Load(group.Users);
context.ExecuteQuery();
int count = group.Users.Count();
FieldUserValue[] values = new FieldUserValue[group.Users.Count()];
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
          {
            FieldUserValue fuv = new FieldUserValue();
            fuv.LookupId = group.Users[i].Id;//THIS WILL WORK FINE
            values[i] = fuv;
          }
User user = context.Web.CurrentUser;
if (group.Users.Any(a => a.Id == user.Id) && (currentItem["Team"] == null || currentItem["Team"].ToString().ToLower() != "cm"))//THIS WILL RAISE AN ERROR
```

now i am able to get the `group.Users[i].Id` without any issue, which on this code `group.Users.Any(a => a.Id == user.Id)` i got this exception :-

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The property or field 'Id' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

so why i can get the `group.Users[i].Id` without loading anything while i can not do the same for `group.Users.Any(a => a.Id == user.Id)`??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you have already loaded group.users in below code:

```
context.Load(group.Users);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

It has requested data from server and the related object has been initialized. So it's able to access *group.Users[i].Id*

The variable user in below code is another object.

```
User user = context.Web.CurrentUser;
```

It has not been initialized (ctx runtime has not send such a request). So we cannot access its ID.